# GIT checkout to master from branch itself updated my local repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I created a new branch and removed one file from my local repository. Then checkedin to my master to merge my branch. But during the checkout itself the repository is updated and when try to merge my branch its says 'Already up-to-date'

```
C:\git\junit [cleanup +0 ~0 -1]> git rm '*.md'
rm 'README.md'
C:\git\junit [cleanup +0 ~0 -2]> git checkout master
D       README.md
D       target/surefire-reports/com.tester.webdriver.MyFristTest.txt
Switched to branch 'master'
**Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.**
C:\git\junit [master +0 ~0 -2]> git merge cleanup
Already up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to `git commit` your changes before switching to the master branch. Git doesn't know to where the changes belong, so it just assumes the changes are for the branch you currently are in.If you specify a branch to where these changes should be documented, the merge would be possible.